# Verificar se os itens de uma lista fazem parte de um conjunto de frases

Tags: python, pandas

Olá!

Eu gostaria de verificar se cada string que faz parte da minha lista (com tamanho varíavel, pois é um input do usuário) está contida nas frases que eu extraí de uma coluna de uma planilha excel através da biblioteca pandas.

Após importar a planilha excel, eu extrai apenas a coluna necessária para o projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consegui criar uma função que itera as frases que estão dentro desse DataFrame, porém as palavras que serão verificadas devem ser inseridas como argumento da função.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de fazer um loop que fizesse isso automaticamente, puxando uma palavra por vez da minha lista com as palavras-chave inputadas pelo usuário. Eu pensei em duas opções que não funcionaram:

1. Utilizar um for dentro do for, mas não funcionou.
2. Utilizar lista[0] onde esse 0 seria incrementado até a última palavra da lista.

Poderiam me ajudar, por favor?

Obrigado desde já! :)

Comment: Dá uma olhada na função [find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#str.find) ela deve te atender perfeitamente

Comment: Amigo, não poste código como imagem - é ruim de ler e a gente não pode copiar para tentar reproduzir localmente.

Answer (score -3):

é possível realizar das duas maneiras que você tentou, percorrer iterando sobre o índice de cada palavra chave de sua lista ou iterando sobre os elementos da sua lista, em muitos casos quando não se sabe o tamanho da lista que será percorrida é melhor utilizar um `while` iterando sobre os índices.

Segue abaixo a maneira iterando sobre os elementos da lista diretamente.

```
def quantidade_respostas():        
    # lista_palavra_chave deve ser uma tupla ou uma lista de strings
    for palavra_chave in lista_palavra_chave: 
        contador=0
        for indice, linha in op_fisica.iteritems():
            contador+=1 if palavra_chave in linha else pass
        print(f'Quantidade de respostas com {}: {}'.format(palavra_chave, contador))
```

Segue abaixo a maneira iterando sobre os índices dos elementos da lista.

```
def quantidade_respostas():        
    index=0
    # lista_palavra_chave deve ser uma tupla ou uma lista de strings
    while index < len(lista_palavra_chave): 
        contador=0
        for indice, linha in op_fisica.iteritems():
            contador+=1 if lista_palavra_chave[index] in linha else pass
        print(f'Quantidade de respostas com {}: {}'.format(lista_palavra_chave[index], contador))
        index+=1
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Marcio! Entendi direitinho e funcionou perfeitamente.